# Variable Pattern on ApexCharts Series

Tags: css, reactjs, apexcharts

I've currently got a working multi-series that's similar to this [Apexcharts example](https://apexcharts.com/react-chart-demos/timeline-charts/multi-series/). Within this series, I am using the `colors` function to specify certain colors depending on certain conditions. For example, as shown in [this example](https://apexcharts.com/docs/options/colors/), I can do:

```
colors: [
  ({ seriesIndex }) => {
    // if one condition, return a color
    // else if another condition, return a different color
  }
]
```

What I'm trying to do now is something similar to create different patterns within the data series, similar to how it's possible to do so with colors. I have tried to look at the `fill` object as specified [here](https://apexcharts.com/docs/options/fill/), but obviously, this will create a standard pattern across **all** data on the graph. I'd like to specify conditions to return different patterns for specific data (like the `colors` function).

Is this possible with Apexcharts? I.e., is there a function that allows me to create conditions based on the seriesIndex to create different patterns? Ultimately, I'd like to create some sort of visual difference for certain data (not in terms of color, but moreso patterns/gradients) so that certain data is easily distinguishable from others. What is the best approach for this?

I have tried to use `linear-gradient` in `colors` but I'm not sure if that is possible. Alternatively, could I create a custom css within the graph options to fulfil this requirement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a possibility built in with the `fill` property that allows you to have different patterns for different series:

```
fill: {
  type: 'pattern',
  opacity: 1,
  pattern: {
    style: ['circles', 'slantedLines', 'verticalLines', 'horizontalLines'], // string or array of strings
  }
},
```

Source: https://apexcharts.com/vue-chart-demos/bar-charts/patterned/

Working example:
https://codesandbox.io/s/happy-stallman-ysyec?file=/src/App.js
(In the example I used multiple fill types for different series - something, that is possible, too)

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. I will give that a try. Just from a quick glance at your example, is it possible to have a different pattern for just “Code” (as an example), rather than having the same patterns mixed across all three series if that makes sense. I’m basically trying to evaluate whether I can explicitly have a pattern only for one row on the graph rather than the same patterns across all.

Comment: Afaik, it is not really possible to have a pattern per value [like you have via colors]. It is not a really bullet-proof idea, but if you know height & amount of your bars, you could think about using as fillType an image that shows the different patterns. See: https://codesandbox.io/s/smoosh-fire-g479m?file=/src/App.js [so I just used a rainbow flag as background, but theoretically you could create an image that uses the patterns you want to show per value; the downside: You would not have different colors anymore. Something that might be possible to fix via border colors?].

Comment: Ok that sounds very interesting. Thank you for that! I will be trying that and will comment further questions if I have any.